# MS Access database on Office 365 with 64-bit version is getting intermittently hang with Linked Oracle tables

Tags: oracle, ms-access

We have MS Access database hosted on desktop which is pulling the data using linked Oracle tables with database hosted on AWS cloud into different region.

MS Access dB with linked tables are getting hanged with following behaviors

1. If we keep any linked table open - It is getting hanged (Not responding) intermittently every 1-2 minutes even though we are not performing any operation on table.
2. Click on any cell within open linked table
3. Navigating from one row to other row in linked table using scroll bar.

MS Access DB Size is around 45 MB.
Network Latency is 200+ ms from Client Desktop to Source database.
Oracle db Version: 12c
MS Access DB Version: Office 365 64 bit MSO (16.0.12730.20394).
MS Access DB is connecting with Oracle database using ODBC driver.

Any insight/guidance is most welcome since we are struggling to resolve the issue since last one month.

Comment: Which ODBC Driver do you use?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: We have used the Oracle 12c 64 bit ODBC driver to connect and pull the data from Oracle database.